# Breakpoint does not hit in Nunit Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, nunit, nsubstitute

I am facing some kind of weird `visual studio` behavior I guess...

I have done Unit Testing in my application using `NUnit`, in some Unit Tests I have used `NFluent` and `NSubstitute` (to make my UT more readable and closer to human language)

Everything worked fine until suddenly I became unable to debug my unit tests.

When I run any test it passes and get green colored.

I figured out that there was a problem when I got an error in my build on `VSTS` and my test doesn't pass unlike in my dev env where every test is ok.

I tried to analyse test by test so I found that I am able to debug Tests made with `NSubstitute` and `NFluent` but tests which are written only using standard `NUnit` are undebugable ...

Here are the actions I made:

> - went to tools-options-test-logging and changed it to "Diagnostics" the way i can understand what is happening ==> found that many .dll
>     are flagged as "unloaded"
> - I double checked that i am on debug environment
> - I clean rebuild / open/ close solution and visual studio

Nothing changed and I am still getting error on VSTS build and no errorson dev env neither I can debug on my local environment...

Any suggestion or solution will be welcome .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into something like that but not exactly (I did not use `NSubstitute`).

double check your project configuration,  in my case the problem was about a difference between project configuration file and the processor type of `visual studio` which was overridden somehow.

I fixed it by modifying the `processor architecture type` to `X64` instead of `Any CPU`.

hope that helps